# How to take input from the user while debugging c++ code in vscode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, mingw32

I tried debugging a CPP source code in C++. I use the MinGW compiler for compiling the code and used the gdb for debugging in vs code. The debugger works fine till it reaches the line which asks for input. The debugger just pauses there, I don't get the option to provide the input anyhow. I will share a screenshot of the debugger upon reaching the input line. Please help me with this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D393T.jpg)

Comment: I don't know VS Code nearly well enough, but what happens when you click the Debug Console Tab that's right beside the Terminal tab?

Comment: Can I use breakpoints? Click F9 or the line to run one line using breakpoints

Comment: Debug console also doesn't respond to inputs, its says something like unable to process while program is running